# Creating a CSS grid layout with images

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a nice grid layout using CSS but can't get them to display in rows of 3 with an individual column row of 33.3333%

The grid style I'm going for is [this](http://focuslabllc.com/work).

Here is the code I have so far;

HTML:

```
    <section id="web">
   <div class="row">
   <span class="web large-3 columns"><img src="images/1.gif"></span>
   <span class="web large-3 columns"><img src="images/2.jpg"></span>
   <span class="web large-3 columns"><img src="images/3.png"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <span class="web large-3 columns"><img src="images/4.jpg"></span>
   <span class="web large-3 columns"><img src="images/5.png"></span>
   <span class="web large-3 columns"><img src="images/6.jpg"></span>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section { display: block; }

section#web {
background: #f8f8f8;
padding: 80px 0;
}

.row {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1144px;
}

span.web {
margin-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

.row .large-3 {
position: relative;
width: 33.33333%;
}

.row .columns {
position: relative;
padding-left: .83333em;
padding-right: .83333em;
width: 100%;
float: left;
}
```

My [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AP2Jw/).

Comment: Could be an issues with the 33.333%, sometimes browsers have different behaviors for decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the width as pixels. Instead, you should use percentages e.g width: 33%. And 33.3 for this layout is a bad choice as you applied 20px for margins. Maybe 28% would be fine.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vfffg/119/

```
.container > div {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 28%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```